# Firefox issue: can't copy or paste (Beta upgrade not helpful / only certain sites)

Tags: css, firefox

Do you know why I can't copy and paste content from one of our websites using Firefox?

I'm aware of Firefox issues with copy/pasting. Upgrading to the latest Beta version does not help. We can copy from certain sites but not other.

Thoughts about this particular website?

Comment: Welcome to the wiki.This type of questions fits for [super-user](http://www.superuser.com)

Comment: Thanks Mohsen - however Nietonfir was right - it was a CSS issue not a software/Firefox or hardware issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because it is disabled via CSS (see inline 50-52):

```
::selection{ background: #;}
::-moz-selection{ background: #;}
::-webkit-selection { background: #;}
```

This means that you can select text, you just don't see the highlighted parts of your selection.

From the [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3a%3aselection%20for%20reference):

> The ::selection CSS pseudo-element applies rules to the portion of a document that has been highlighted (e.g., selected with the mouse or another pointing device) by the user.

There are some more CSS declarations on your linked page that disable the selection of images, etc.

Comment: Since it's Tinymce, it could also be this bug, which causes inconsistent Ctrl+V and right click paste behavior. http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/26540#ticket